# macOS Terminal Emulator in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, terminal-emulator

I'm trying to create a Terminal emulator using the Swift Language (currently on Swift 4.0)

So far I've created a UI and everything the only issue is that some of my commands don't work such as:

```
diskutil mount disk0s1
```

which would give me the following error in the Xcode console output:

```
"Could not start up a DiskManagement session"
```

Some commands work such as:

```
echo Hi
```

Here is the code I have so far that actually does the command:

```
@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    let cmd = args.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
    task.arguments = cmd
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out after dwelling on this for 5 hours. Within the entitlements file, you need to change App Sandbox to NO.

Comment: Do you have a repo link for this project? GitHub or something?